# why does my "img" tag not work?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to link an image to a website i'm building but i am having trouble linking the img. It's on my desktop and i believe i've taken the right steps, but i keep getting a "broken image symbol". Please take a look at the code and let me know if anything is wrong.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container"> 
    </div> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <img class="logo" src="img/mainLogo.gif" ng-click="redirect('#')">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- insert rows here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>  <!-- End of Container -->
</nav> <!-- End Nav Bar here -->
```

Comment: Where is your file located?

Comment: in a folder on my desktop

Comment: where is this `html` located? u need to create `img` folder in the folder where your this `html` page is located and then place your `mainLogo.gif` in the image folder~

Comment: yeah the img is located in a folder titled "img" inside my main project folder!

Comment: is this html located in the main project folder?

Comment: Try it by using ../img/mainLogo.gif

Comment: FYI I don't think that solves the problem, but there's one too many `</div>` the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Ok first moan - indent your code (unless its just from copying and pasting into SO and it messed the format, in which case - sorry for the moan xD)

I have a feeling, the image isn't showing because it's 404'ing - if you open up the browser console / firebug it should show you if it's 404'ing

secondly, you're using images src correctly but is the file structure? Should be something like:

```
html
    index.php
    somepage.php
    img
        img1.jpg
        img2.jpg
```

this means that if you called img in index.php like:

```
<img src="img/img1.jpg" class="some-class" id="some-id" />
```

it should show - let me know if it works :)

(notes)

don't have to be a .php file - tis just what I'm used to

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing your tag properly! Do this:

```
<img class="logo" src="img/mainLogo.gif" ng-click="redirect('#')"/>
```

Also, make sure that your path is correct, you are using a relative path for your project. Can you post your project structure?

Comment: This isn't actually needed in order for an image to be displayed

Comment: In that case, you have the incorrect pathing to your img

Comment: It's because your image is not where you are telling the browser it should be. Check your path in `src`